# Change Day language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

My config is set in French:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

However Day.name does not provide a day in French. How could I do that?

```
Day.new(day, day_from_date(format_day(day), month, year))
```

EDIT:

```
@expense = current_user.expenses.create(ref: @current_date, year: session[:current_year], month: session[:current_month],
                            days: @calendar)
```

`@calendar` being an array of `Days`. I'm getting an error in the rails console when I try to display the records but it seems to be working in the View (days' names are displayed).

```
t.string :days
```

In the Model:

```
serialize :days
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the most up-to-date [french locale file](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml). According to that file, the Day names exist.

Comment: For that, `rails-i18n` gem should be installed. So the solution is to install the gem. I've almost written this myself until I dug up existing answers :)

Comment: You don't need to install the Gem. Copy the `fr.yml` file inside your `config/locales/` directory, and you're done.

Comment: This is still considered a [manual installation](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n#manual-installation). The point is, it's not included by default.

Comment: Yet you assume this file is already present. No big deal, hopefully comments are read too.

Comment: This fr. file already exists. I also added the gem but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to restart the server after you update the file. I recommend just copy the file, not the entire gem.

Comment: Hum that still doesn't work. It's weird. Could it be because I have a record that stores an array of Days? See original post.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a french locale at `config/locales/fr.yml` and add this:

```
fr:
  date:
    abbr_day_names:
    - Lu
    _ etc.
   day_names:
    - Lundi
    - etc.
```